# Change TextView text in a custom ListView adapter

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I'm creating a currency converter in Android Studio as part of a uni assignment and I have a custom ListView adapter with each list item showing country name, country code, and a TextView that I would like to output the converted amount.

Basically the activity has a Spinner and an EditText components, and I want when a value is entered in the EditText, the TextView of every ListView item being updated to the converted amount for that specific country depending on the Spinner selection.
I have everything set up and the ListView is populated properly with the country names, I just don't know how to update the TextView of a ListView in the activity code instead of in the class code for the adapter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should iterate through all view's inside your listview and get textview of each one. some thing like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < listview.getCount(); i++) {
    TextView  et = (TextView ) listview.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
    if (et!=null) {
       // change your text view here 
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works, however I'm having the issue of only being able to get the listView items that are currently visible. Any workaround for that?